# Deezer Api - Get Related / Similar Tracks for a Track ID

Tags: deezer

Is there a way to get similar or **related Tracks** for a given **Deezer Track-ID**?

Soundcloud and YouTube both have such an service, but I can't find one in the Deezer Api Documentation.

Does anyone know the name of the api-endpoint for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, there is no endpoint to get the related tracks to a Deezer track ID. However, you can get the related artists like written in the documentation : http://developers.deezer.com/api/artist#connections

Comment: Thank you for the clarification, and that link to the artists api is really nice, did not think about that, looks like a good start to write some own "related tracks" code:)